# How to start array from beginning without crashing?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode, function

I have an array with 10 items. When the count reaches 10 I would like it to begin from the beginning ( index 0 ) without crashing.

Here is sample code

```
 myLabel.text = myArray[arrayIndex]

         arrayIndex += 1
```

How would you go about doing this?

Thanks!

Comment: `arrayIndex = (arrayIndex + 1) % myArray.count`

Comment: Thanks I will ry this out!

Answer (score -1):

I actually found a work around!

```
var arrayIndex = 0

@IBAction func myButton(sender: AnyObject) {


    if arrayIndex <= myArray.endIndex - 1{

         myLabel.text = myArray[arrayIndex]

        arrayIndex += 1

    }else {

        arrayIndex = 0
    }    

}
```